# line not showing on image jframe

Tags: java, swing

```
package carspeedometer;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class a1 {

    a1() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Speedometer");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JLabel jb = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                "C:/Users/Vinayak/Desktop/tester.jpg"));
        jp.add(jb);

        jf.add(jp);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(700, 700);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(70, 70, 200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String...s) {
        new a1();
    }
}
```

Line is not showing on screen.I want to show line on top of the image.please help.
Here i am trying to build a speedometer but first a line needs to be displayed

Comment: If you want to make one just for the exercise, just go ahead. Otherwise you might want to consider using a [third party lib](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.be/2010/08/java-swing-component-library.html)

Comment: Moreover, please do read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), if this is really not a known thingy for you :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can only draw in Swing if you *override* a drawing method of a component. Here your paint method overrides nothing because your class extends nothing. I suggest

- that you create a class that extends JPanel
- that you override the JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method
- that you use the `@Override` annotation to verify the override
- that you place the JPanel into a JFrame and display it and
- that you read the [Swing Painting Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). You don't want to guess at this stuff.